# Override AccountController in Individual User Accounts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've created in Asp .Net Core 2.1 - mvc Individual User Accounts and add **scaffold identity**. 
I need override route `Identity/Account/Register` to `Account/Register`.
 I guess I need access in AccountController and add attr `[Route("")]`. 
How can i do it?. 
In advance thanks for help.

Comment: In ASP.NET Core 2.1 you cannot do that! This is really a bad thing Microsoft had done removing the mvc support for identity in ASP.NET Core 2.1 +. One solution is that you can generate the identity in asp.net core 2.0 project and then copy the identity related code to asp.net core 2.1 project.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the latest Identity, there is no longer an `AccountController`. The ASP.NET Core team have made the (controversial) decision to move everything to Razor Pages. The old Identity scaffold of authentication and account management controllers and views now exists as the "default UI", which is included by default when you use `AddDefaultIdentity`. That method internally calls `AddDefaultUI`.

To modify the default UI, you must scaffold the pieces you desire into your project, which can be accomplished via right-clicking on your project in the solution explorer and choosing Add > New Scaffolded Item... That will then give you a window where you can choose among various available scaffolds, one of which is Identity. Selecting that option will pop another window allowing you to choose which Razor Pages you would like to scaffold. You can choose any or all. Since the default UI remains included, the scaffolded pages function as overrides, so anything not included falls back to the default UI version.

If you abhor Razor Pages as I and many others do and want the old-style MVC controllers and views back, you now have no choice but to create them yourself. You can scaffold all the Identity pages into your project as a guide and then shuffle the code into your controller(s) and views. Then, simply delete the scaffolded pages when you're done. You'll also need to use `AddIdentity` in `ConfigureServices` instead of `AddDefaultIdentity`, or the default UI will still take precedence. It's frankly a pain in the butt, but that's how it is.